Vimeo Embed Loading Issue
I have embedded the vimeo player in iframe. Sometimes the page showing error. "Sorry the video not exists." but when I refresh the page its working fine.
I tried the solution Link. Still no luck. I am attaching the error image.
I have a set of videos as a playlist. one plays after another. Getting errors in the first video or inbetween videos.
this is the iframe I am using
<p><iframe class="iframe-body" id="VimeoVideoElement-2575" allow="autoplay" style="min-height: 60vh;" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/video_id?autoplay=true&player_id=2575" width="100%"  frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe><span>Click on reload button if the video is not loading</span> <button role="button" type="button"  class="ml-2 btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-sm" onclick="handleVimeoVideo()">Reload <i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></p> 
id="VimeoVideoElement-2575" -  unique for all videos


